# Executing callback immediately after map_async finishes

Tags: python, python-multithreading

I'm using map_async with processes that return a ton of data.  The normal map_async results in the data being stored in memory, then returned when everything is processed.  To get around this, I've used a generator approach from:

[Combining itertools and multiprocessing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7306522/combining-itertools-and-multiprocessing)

However, this doesn't make full use of multi-threading (as in, if you have 29 threads finished and 1 thread hanging, it won't start the next batch of jobs until everyone is done).  Is there a way to have the map_async or does there exist a similar function which will send its returns to a callback function as each thread finishes?

Comment: not clear if you're using threads or sub processes?

Comment: I'm using subprocesses.  I think using apply_async though is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is to use a producer-consumer-based solution.  The producer puts tasks in a `multiprocessing.Queue`, and the consumers (subprocesses) get and processes them, in a loop.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13980160/multiprocessing-producer-consumer-design) is a good SO question with a (detailed) possible solution.